# how to link 2 rows in same table mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, rows

I have a table of users and i need to link two rows in it. i.e I want one user to have a link to another one.

Is it possible to do so using mysql in php?

or if not please suggest me some otther way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a self-join:

```sql
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM   my_table a JOIN my_table b ON a.foo = b.bar
```

To permanently store a "link" between two records, you can create a relationship table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE relationships (
  id_a BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  id_b BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_a, id_b),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_a) REFERENCES my_table (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_b) REFERENCES my_table (id)
);
```

Comment: i want to add that friend request concpt here

Answer (score 0):

Look up self joins, a quick Google should give you the answer you require.

Comment: no it didnt gave thats why asked it here

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship is many-to-many (i.e., each user may have links to many other users) the best way to do this is with a second table listing the relationships.

```
user_links (
    user_a_id int not null,
    user_b_id int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_a_id, user_b_id)
)
```

You may want to read up on [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).